# Other word for a person who does something to others but doesn't like it done to them

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

This is a duplicate question but has still not been answered for me. I'm so close to the exact word — I know there is one out there — but the closest word I can find is a **hypocrite**:

> A person who claims to have certain moral principles or beliefs, but behaves in a way that shows they are not sincere.

The word I'm looking for is for: a person who does not **claim** things, but **does** things to another that they'd consider wrong or immoral to have done to them.

Comment: This is just hypocrisy of moral belief as put into action; I don't think there's a word that distinguishes the belief from the act that implements the belief.

Comment: [*Two-faced*](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=two-faced+meaning), perhaps

Comment: The person has a *double standard*. (And no, that does **not** mean that the person is being *two-faced*.)

Answer (score 2):

I will offer a phrase and a single word.

**[*He can dish it out, but he can't take it.*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/someone-can-dish-it-out-but-he-or-she-can-t-take-it)**

> Someone easily criticizes other people but does not like it when other people criticize him or her: *He’s mad at me for teasing him – he can dish it out, but he can’t take it!*

*(Cambridge Dictionary)*

Example: [Donald Trump can dish it out but he can't take it](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2016/nov/21/donald-trump-can-dish-it-out-but-he-cant-take-it)

***narcissist***

The connection between this and your description isn't apparent from the dictionary definition, but [this article](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/evolution-the-self/201110/the-narcissists-dilemma-they-can-dish-it-out) explains the connection.  Here is an excerpt:

> When criticized, narcissists show themselves woefully incapable of retaining any emotional poise, or receptivity. And it really doesn't much matter whether the nature of that criticism is constructive or destructive. They just don't seem to be able to take criticism, period. At the same time, these disturbed individuals demonstrate an abnormally developed capacity to criticize others (as in, "dish it out" to them).

Answer (score 0):

These people are called a "Sean" or a "Shanna".  Like the "Karen" or "Todd".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This would be a very good answer if this is in fact the case, but right now, we don't have any indication that it is. If you could link a definition, this would be far more useful.